# Eclipse 2020-03 freezes after selecting the workspace

Tags: eclipse, log4j

All,
I've installed Eclipse 2020-03. When I run it, it freezes after selecting the workspace. Enabling the console I get this message:

*osgi> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileSnapshot).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.*

Running the application with *-debug -console* I get the following text:

```
Start VM: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-Djava.class.path=C:\Programs\eclipse\ccp_eclipse_2020_03\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher C:\Programs\eclipse\ccp_eclipse_2020_03\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library C:\Users\rosario martorana\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1100.v20190907-0426\eclipse_1902.dll
-startup C:\Programs\eclipse\ccp_eclipse_2020_03\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-debug
-console
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241\bin\server\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-Djava.class.path=C:\Programs\eclipse\ccp_eclipse_2020_03\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar
Install location:
    file:/c:/Programs/eclipse/ccp_eclipse_2020_03/eclipse/
Configuration file:
    file:/c:/Programs/eclipse/ccp_eclipse_2020_03/eclipse/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/c:/Programs/eclipse/ccp_eclipse_2020_03/eclipse/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/C:/Users/rosario martorana/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.15.200.v20200214-1600.jar
Loading extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.1.700.v20200207-2156.jar
        eclipse.properties not found
Framework classpath:
    file:/C:/Users/rosario martorana/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.15.200.v20200214-1600.jar
    file:/C:/Users/rosario martorana/.p2/pool/plugins/
    file:/C:/Users/rosario martorana/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.1.700.v20200207-2156.jar
Splash location:
    C:\Users\rosario martorana\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.15.0.v20200305-0155\splash.bmp
Debug options:
    file:/C:/Users/martorar/Desktop/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 14
Starting application: 3853
osgi> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileSnapshot).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Any idea?

Thanks,
  Rosario

Comment: Does a fresh workspace work (`eclipse -data <path-to-an-empty-directory>`)? What's in the `<workspace>/.log` file?

Comment: Problem solved after installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. The problem was connected to the missing bash console.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. The problem was connected to the missing bash console.